# NetBeans + TestNG -> "Go to source" is not possible

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, testng

I have an huge maven project with TestNG tests. I create an new test file and add tests to it to clean my code out of bugs. I use NetBeans to run TestNG tests.

These are my issues:

1. The output of the tests is in text form. When I have got an stack trace, its elements are not hyperlinks (so they are not clickable). Rightclick + "Go to source" is also not possible. So I have to manually search for the class and the line with the error.
2. The output of the test is in text form, not like in this example: http://wiki.netbeans.org/TestNG

How could I get the stacktraces clickable?

P.P I use Netbeans 8.1.
Today I installed all pending plugin updates but the described behavior has not changed.

P.P.2 I start tests via Run -> Test File [Ctrl+F6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to two reported bugs in Netbeans.

[#257563](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=257563) - surefire 2.19.1 show no test results windows

solution: downgrade to surefire plugin version 2.18.1

[#255883](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=255883) - test results windows isn't displayed

solution: untick in the options `Java -> Maven -> print maven output loggin level`

Comment: Downgrading to surefire plugin version 2.18.1 caused test results windows to be displayed. "print maven output loggin level" was unchecked. 10x